# image cutting in opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I want to segment some Bangali scripts. While segmenting the lines I get my expected image for the 1st line. But from 2nd lines I'am getting a whole black image. Here is my code for cutting.

```
def linecut(line_start,line_end,name):
    print("called" , name)
    #imArray = np.asarray(im)
    print("Start=",line_start,"end=",line_end)
    # create mask
    plygn = line_start
    i=len(line_end)-1
    while i>=0:
        plygn.append(line_end[i])
        i-=1
    print(plygn)
    #print(imArray.shape)
    region = Polygon(plygn)

    for index, pixel in np.ndenumerate(pixels):
        # Unpack the index.
        row, col, channel = index
        # We only need to look at spatial pixel data for one of the four channels.
        if channel != 0:
            continue
        point = Point(row, col)
        if not region.contains(point):
            im_copy[(row, col, 0)] = 255
            im_copy[(row, col, 1)] = 255
            im_copy[(row, col, 2)] = 255
            im_copy[(row, col, 3)] = 0
    im_name = str(name)+".png"
    cut_image = Image.fromarray(im_copy)
    plygn.clear()
    cut_image.save('F:\\relax' +im_name)
    cut_image.__del__()][1]
```

images: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kiHXPS9wA2rvUAygeuvI3Q7Wq0njkjuL

Comment: You forgot to post your images

Comment: sorry I forgot the images. thanks @DmitriiZ.